# Trouble to help me a little C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin) ) != '\n' && ch != EOF){
        fputc(ch, stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Why I see is not a character to enter a character on the console, but in the press the Enter key together after all the output, the key is that I close the output buffer and refresh the output buffer.

Comment: Please format the question better and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Note that [the `fgetc` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. This is important to make your comparison to `EOF` work reliably.

Comment: You are using `setbuf()` for `stdout` which is buffered, why do you think that would affect the input?

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, I mean that it will not make characters print instantly which is what you apparently want. To achieve such behavior you should work directly with the serial interface for your terminal.

Comment: Actually, the problem is on the input side and is out of your program. It is a property of the terminal (and OS) that the input is available to your program only after having typed the whole line. If you are under Linux, try to type ^D (Control-D) after each character to send it to your program char by char.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for pointing out my mistake

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I tried to enter the buffer and the output buffer is closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, terminals are in *canonical mode*, where the input is passed to the program only when a line delimiter (newline, end of input at the start of a line, and so on) is typed.

The way to manipulate the terminal -- for example, to get keypresses immediately when they occur -- varies between operating systems. The Curses libraries ([PDCurses](https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCurses) for Windows, ncurses for just about all others) hide the differences under a single interface, so you might wish to look into that.

Comment: I understand what you mean, this is the cause of the OS, not the cause of the program

Comment: @fangxing: Yes.